# Is something wrong with the password change page on Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

Using Django 3.16, going into the admin console and managing a user (**admin/auth/user/412/change/** in the example of user id 412), I attempt to change the user password by clicking on the link "*you can change the password using **this form***".

[image]

But when I click on the link I get the error "User with ID "412/password" doesn't exist". It's like the URL settings aren't pulling the PK/ID out of the URL properly.

[image]

(You'll see I'm using the Grappelli styling for the admin console. I've tested it without Grappelli and I get the same errors.)

My urls.py has the usual line `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)`.

Is there some reason why this might be happening, or something I can do about it?

thanks

John

Further investigation shows it's only when I use a custom User Admin form, as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username','first_name', 'last_name','email','is_superuser','is_staff','is_active','last_login')
    list_editable = ('is_active','is_superuser','is_staff')
    form = UserChangeForm
    list_filter = ('is_superuser','is_active','is_staff','last_login')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Is there something wrong with my line `form = UserChangeForm`?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the problem was I was using a ModelAdmin form, rather than a UserAdmin form, as my custom class.

The custom class needs to look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email','is_superuser','is_staff','is_active','last_login')
    list_editable = ('is_active','is_superuser','is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_superuser','is_active','is_staff','last_login')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AbstractBaseClass you need to give path of your CustomBackend in settings file

Comment: I'm not using AbstractBaseClass. Any other thoughts?

Comment: can you share your git link for this project if possible? I will try to look from base

Comment: I've discovered it's caused by using a custom user admin page (see what I added to the bottom of my question) but I still don't know how to fix it!